Azure DPS Java exception - javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version
I have been debugging this issue since over days and tried many different options but still no luck and running out of ideas to resolve this error while provisioning the device. What exactly is the root cause of the error here? Do I need to check back in my configurations as I am able to make connection to the event hub? I am using this following example from the azure github repo to provision the device and getting the below exception. Using java version 21
Example provided from Azure
https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-java/blob/main/provisioning/provisioning-device-client-samples/provisioning-X509-sample/src/main/java/samples/com/microsoft/azure/sdk/iot/ProvisioningX509Sample.java
ERROR STACK TRACE
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot.provisioning.device.internal.exceptions.ProvisioningDeviceTransportException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version

Error is causing while trying to register the device, not sure if I have to add anything related to TLS or SSL config before creating this client?
  ProvisioningDeviceClient provisioningDeviceClient = ProvisioningDeviceClient.create(
            GLOBAL_ENDPOINT,
            ID_SCOPE,
            PROVISIONING_DEVICE_CLIENT_TRANSPORT_PROTOCOL,
            securityProviderX509);
    ProvisioningDeviceClientRegistrationResult provisioningDeviceClientRegistrationResult = provisioningDeviceClient.registerDeviceSync();


This is about the TLS protocol version. Nothing to do with your certificates, X509, etc.

Is there anything I have to do to set the TLS protocol? I am using java 21

@Sam are you facing SSLHandshakeException locally or on the Azure web app?/trying the code locally or on Azure?

@Sam Refer to Transport Layer Security (TLS) support in IoT                 Hub

Add and manage TLS/SSL certificates in                           Azure App Service

I followed this Document to Provision an X.509 certificate simulated device to Microsoft Azure IoT Hub using java.
References for Transport Layer Security (TLS) support  in IoT Hub can be found in the Azure documentation for IoT Hub TLS support,
Open a Windows command prompt and clone the Azure IoT Samples for Java GitHub repository:
git clone https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-java.git --recursive

Navigate to the cloned repository:
cd azure-iot-sdk-java

Build the project to download all needed packages:
mvn install -DskipTests=true

Create a Self-Signed X.509 Device Certificate:

Open Git Bash and navigate to a directory where you'd like to create your certificates.
Run the following command to generate the certificate and private key:

winpty openssl req -outform PEM -x509 -sha256 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout device-key.pem -out device-cert.pem -days 30 -extensions usr_cert -addext extendedKeyUsage=clientAuth -subj "//CN=my-x509-device"


When prompted for a pass phrase, use 1234 twice.
Verify the generated certificate's properties by running:

winpty openssl x509 -in device-cert.pem -text -noout

Prepare and Run the Device Provisioning Code:

Copy the ID Scope and Global device endpoint values from the Azure portal.
Navigate to the sample project folder:

cd provisioning\provisioning-device-client-samples\provisioning-X509-sample


Open.\src\main\java\samples\com\microsoft\azure\sdk\iot\ProvisioningX509Sample.java
in an editor.
Update the idScope and globalEndpoint variables with your ID scope and provisioning service global endpoint.
Update the leafPublicPem and leafPrivateKey variables with the content of device-cert.pem and unencrypted-device-key.pem respectively.
Build the sample:

mvn clean install


Navigate to the target folder:

cd target


Run the .jar file:

java -jar ./provisioning-x509-sample-{version}-with-deps.jar

like this :
java -jar ./provisioning-x509-sample-1.0.0-with-deps.jar

you can find in arget

Confirm Your Device Provisioning Registration:

Go to your Device Provisioning Service in the Azure portal.
Select Manage enrollments from the Settings menu.
Check the registration status of your individual enrollment. It should show the assigned IoT hub and device ID.
Go to your IoT hub and verify that the device is registered.



Thanks Sampath for the detail example above. I tried the exact steps however getting the same exception as below, so no clue what is happening
com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot.provisioning.device.internal.exceptions.ProvisioningDeviceTransportException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version

The error TLS occurs due to the local TLS setting (or) Azure TLS setting. Refer to this doc for local. Refer this so and doc to Transport Layer Security (TLS) support in IoT Hub.
